# 'LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble' when using \externaldocument

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files, xr

I'm using 'xr' package for cross referencing across files. I have three files named 'main', 'file1' and 'file2' where all the packages are decalred in the main file.  I'm including the files in the main file using the \include command.

The content is in the other two files. Now I've to refer to an equation in file1 from from file2.

So I used \externaldocument{file1} in file2. It resulted in an error.

**'LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble'**

Then I used \externaldocument{file1} in main but it resulted in many warnings saying that
      **'LaTeX Warning: Label `kcl' multiply defined'.**

Please help in eliminating these warnings

Comment: Don't use the xr-package for this. You don't have an external document if you use \include. \ref will work without it.

Answer (score 1):

## Clarification

If I understand your question correctly, this is how your files are structured.

### File: main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% ---- Load Packages ----
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Use UTF8 encoding
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \title{Some MWE}
    \author{Samuel}
    \maketitle

    % Include file1.tex
    \input{./file1}

    % Include file2.tex
    \input{./file2}

\end{document}
```

### File: file1.tex

```
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Method}
\label{sec:method}
\lipsum[1-2]
```

### File: file2.tex

```
\section{Results}
\label{sec:results}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Conclusion}
\label{sec:conc}
\lipsum[1-2]
\par As seen in section~\ref{sec:intro}, we know that we can
link back to it from a separate file!
```

## Solution

If you noticed, I've sneaked the solution in above. In the main file I specified the preamble, the packages to be used and declared the document structure.

In the body of the main document (`main.tex`), I have used the `\input{...}` command to take the contents of the other `.tex` files named `file1.tex` and `file2.tex` and inject it at the points specified.

When compiled, the file looks like this: (tidied for clarity)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

% ---- Load Packages ----
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Use UTF8 encoding
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \title{Some MWE}
    \author{Samuel}
    \maketitle

    % Include file1.tex
    \section{Introduction}
    \label{sec:intro}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \section{Method}
    \label{sec:method}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    % Include file2.tex
    \section{Results}
    \label{sec:results}
    \lipsum[1-2]

    \section{Conclusion}
    \label{sec:conc}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \par As seen in section~\ref{sec:intro}, we know that we can
    link back to it from a separate file!

\end{document}
```

From the above, you can see that the cross referencing will work just fine with the standard `\ref` and `\ref*` and also their enhanced forms such as when used with the `hyperref` package as above.